# Self-project and CSP

Tags: javascript, html, security, content-security-policy

I'm pretty confused on understanding CSP. Based on the docs and some YouTube videos, if I wanted to add CSP into my website I can do a **meta** tag like so,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://kit.fontawesome.com/----.js; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/--- 'unsafe-inline'; img-src'self' ;">
```

My true objective is to simply block XSS attacks within my form on the site, or other types of attacks in general. I understand I can write some JavaScript and implement an escaper function but I've read CSP will do majority of the work.

Now **'self'** is suppose to use all script/images/css within that project (origin) correct? Or am I misunderstanding something. I've searched thru stackoverflow, google and youtube but not finding an answer for this. Everytime I try to adjust it accordingly, either all my data disappears (which I believe its because of the google font) or it gets sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome then you should open up your developer tools and see what errors are printed out in the console. Chrome will alert you if a resource is blocked by your Content-Security-Policy.

Also, depending on your situation you may want to look into the [Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only) as it may allow you to implement your changes in smaller steps.